# How to disable sending all sensible information to the cloud?

Tags: security, cloud

Recently I found, that my Samsung Galaxy S7 was sending all my photos to Samsung without my explicit permission. I would like to ban any such activity from any application. Is it possible to do this centralized?

---

I can't search for dozens of allications, I need some centralized solution.

Comment: Sending all your photos to Samsung? Do you have an example/proof of this? It may be helpful to see if this is also occurring on other similar devices.

Comment: If you want to ban *any* such activity, you either need to turn off your Internet connection completely – or use a custom ROM without any proprietary components/apps. The behavior you describe for photos is known e.g. with "Google Photos" (which automatically backs them up to Google servers). You could check if there's a similar Samsung app, and disable it.

Comment: Yeah everyone with Samsung device just received your pictures. It is called backup if you don't want it just disable it in app that is responsible for that eg Google photos. And if you want to ban sharing any info to internet than get rid of all smartphones/smart devices and computers. Also terminate internet connection and you are good to go. Optionally you can build Faraday's cage around house or use portable one to bring with you everywhere.

Comment: @Izzy I need something less radical. Some application, which looks for it, some "antispy" tool or some cheklist document.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје please don't There is no rational reason to send my pictures to Samsung by default, it is just spying and I need a tool to prevent it.

Comment: @Dims unfortunately there isn't anything "less radical" if you really want to prevent it completely. Many of those "spy apps" come pre-installed with the device and are deeply integrated with the system (so even "disabling" them doesn't prevent them from spying in the background). Root access provided you can certainly minimize the risk, but not disabling it completely. The companies behind this are "valuing" your privacy (i.e. they make money out of your private data).

Comment: It's not sending pictures to Samsung it's backup for god's sake. Look every app, every site you visit online collect your data deal with it or not, if you have Facebook or any Google app you shared everything already. So just disable that backup and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

**Option One:**

Turn off that specific app's ability to sync to the cloud.

**Option Two:**

Disable app

**Option Three:**

Disable internet connection for device

**Option Four:**

Get rid of all internet connected devices.